# Swift Alamofire 4 add header to request without custom request adapter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to migrate to the new alamofire, and in the docs it tells me i need to do a custom request adapter in order to add headers to requests, i think thats not confortable everywhere and i would like to just add the header in the request instead of having to make an adaper for certain requests, anyone have found a way to do it?

below i shared my old code (commented) and my new code wich is missing a header parameter.

```
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post , parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds) + Double(1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                            self.loadAreasFromServer();
                            self.busy = false;
                        }
                    }
            }

            /*Alamofire.request(.POST, url,headers:headers,parameters:parameters,
                encoding: .json)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        let time = DispatchTime(DispatchTime.now()) + Double(1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                            self.loadAreasFromServer();
                            self.busy = false;
                        }
                    }
            }*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature changed. This should work for you:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post , parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds) + Double(1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                self.loadAreasFromServer();
                self.busy = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i could not find this in the documentation!

Comment: Welcome, glad that I could help you! A little hint for the next time. You can use the Xcode autocompletion and this will show you how the current signature of a method looks like